# How to browse / locate MS Word and display it using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vb.net-2010

I try to follow this [LINK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316383) but this tutorial is viewing direct an MS Word that has already an data to it.

I also try this code below

```
  Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("G:\Folder\NewFolder\HHHHH.docx")
    objWord.Visible = True
```

but this code is fix that if the MS Word it in that path and view it.

All I want to achieve is Browse the MS Word wherever it is located on my PC and display it in the form. And if possible click a button and preview it in crystal report. So I can print it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you can't just use a `WebBrowser` control?  You can simply `Navigate` to the path of a Word document and it will load the appropriate ActiveX control automatically, assuming that Word is installed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry i am new to this. any suggestion is fine with me as long it achieve.

Comment: @jmcilhinney do you any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I told you what to do.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes please

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenFileDialog:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim filedialog As New OpenFileDialog

    filedialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    filedialog.Filter = "Word Files|*.docx"
    filedialog.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

works fine for me.